# PhpMyAdmin Missing parameter

Tags: phpmyadmin

Everything was working fine until this moment I want to create a new database and I'm receiving this error

```
db_create.php: Missing parameter: new_db (FAQ 2.8)
```

Also when I was trying to export my database I also receive the following error

```
export.php: Missing parameter: what (FAQ 2.8)
export.php: Missing parameter: export_type (FAQ 2.8)
```

When I looked it FAQ 2.8 from the suggested link in PHPMYADMIN

> 2.8 I get "Missing parameters" errors, what can I do?
>
> Here are a few points to check:
>
> - In config.inc.php, try to leave the $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] directive    empty. See also FAQ 4.7.
> - Maybe you have a broken PHP installation or you need to upgrade your    Zend Optimizer. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31134.
> - If you are using Hardened PHP with the ini directive    varfilter.max_request_variables set to the default (200) or another
>     low value, you could get this error if your table has a high number
>     of columns. Adjust this setting accordingly. (Thanks to Klaus
>     Dorninger for the hint).
> - In the php.ini directive arg_separator.input, a value of ";" will    cause this error. Replace it with "&;".
> - If you are using Hardened-PHP, you might want to increase request    limits.
> - The directory specified in the php.ini directive session.save_path    does not exist or is read-only.

I did tried with php.ini to make sure that I've `session.save_path = "/tmp"`

I'm using Mac Xserver and running with `MAMP` I did tried everything to restart my server and nothing help.

Can someone please make a suggestion on the same?

My apologies if I have posted this in the wrong place!

Comment: I don't have an answer but your question might be better targeted on the PMA forums http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/forums/forum/72909 Your issue sounds pretty application specific

Answer (score 1):

This might also happen if you disable the cookies in your browser.
If this is the case, you may see this message:"Cookies must be enabled past this point" on the top of Phpmyadmin page.
All you need to do is to enable cookies on your browser, or use different browser to log to phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Google Chrome. Using Internet Explorer everything works like a charm / as before.

And after resolving an issue with my Firefox extensions, Firefox now works as well.

And to be semi-complete in Opera everything is fine, too.